# C language getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I'm a new C language learner and I have a problem below, I tried to print name out but it did not print. This is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char name;
    int len = 0;

    printf("Enter the user name: ");
    name = getchar();

    while (name != '\n')
    {
        len++;
        name = getchar();
    }

    printf("char = %d\n", len);
    printf("name = ");
    putchar(name);

    return (0); 
}
```

output:

```
Enter the user name: abcd
len = 4
name =
```

it should print out `name = abcd`.

I appreciate that and thank you!

Comment: `char name;` : `name`  can hold only one character.

Comment: so what should I do now? please @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Prepare the array as the place to save the input. [sample code](https://ideone.com/h1tOpH)

Comment: You are literally outputting '\n'.

Comment: Off-topic since a fix-my-code request. Please read a good C book and some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sorry but just tell me what should I do instead of fix my code!

Comment: You should take a few weeks to learn programming in C. So take a good book (or several ones) and read it. You are lacking basic knowledge about programming. Perhaps reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) - an excellent introduction to programming (which does *not* use C) should be helpful too

Comment: Note that the value returned by `getchar()` is an `int`, not a `char`, because it has to be able to return any character and a distinct value `EOF`.  You should also handle EOF in your input loop, ideally (because if your existing code encounters EOF, the programs continues running for a long, long, long time).

Answer (score 4):

`getchar()` and `putchar()` can only handle a *single* character at a time. 
Since you need to store a string which is basically a sequence of characters, you need to declare `name` as a character array.

You can't use `putchar()` to print a string. Try `puts()` or `printf()`.

And add a `\0` character to denote the end of string when you encounter the '\n' at which point you stop reading.

```
char name[20];
int len = 0;

printf("Enter the user name: ");
name[len] = getchar();

while (name[len] != '\n')
{
    name[++len] = getchar();
}
name[++len]='\0';
```

If `putchar()` must be used to print the string, you have the length of the string in `len`. Make a loop with a variable `i=0` and keep iterating as long as `i<len` while incrementing `i` by `1`

```
for(i=0; i<len; ++i)
{
    putchar(name[i]);
}
```

You might want to do some error checking to ensure that [`getchar()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) worked properly. It will return `EOF` on error.
And `name` should be big enough to hold the input string.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` and `putchar()` handles only single character.

#### getchar()-

is an input function. It is used to read one character at a time from console input (generally keyboard). 
Ex:

```
char c=getchar();
```

#### putchar()-

is an output function. It is used to display one character at a time onto console output (generally monitor). It accepts one argument of character type. 
Ex:

```
char c;
putchar(c);
```

you should use `gets()` and `puts()` to work with strings or you can use `printf()` and `scanf()`

Comment: `gets` has been is deprecated for over 10 (or was it 20) years.

Answer (score 0):

Learn about the concept of array in C first.

Use `scanf()` and `printf()` like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter the name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);

    printf("Name: %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, should use `fgets`  not `scanf`

Comment: yeah, but the problem says I have to use getchar() and putchar() to read the input. Sorry!!

Comment: `scanf("%s", name)` instead of `scanf("%s", &name)`

Comment: sorry but I need to use getchar() and putchar() instead of scanf @J...S

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can take input and print using getchar() and putchar().

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
int name;
printf("Enter the user name: ");
    while ((name = getchar()) != EOF)
         putchar(name);
    return 0;
    }
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to learn more about programming and about [data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure). I would recommend [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), an excellent and freely available introduction to programming (which is *not* about C).

You need to learn more of C. Notably about [arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) (but they have limitations, I leave you to find out which ones), perhaps `struct`, pointers, [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). That should take you a few weeks, and you need to read several books (and also some reference material like [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), perhaps glance also into the specification of C11, i.e. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)).

<sup>(ask yourself what would or should happen if the user of your program entered a name of 50 letters, or even a million ones; and what about "wrong" input, e.g. digits or punctuation? think about what a name really is inside a computer)</sup>

Since you are required to only use [getchar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) and [putchar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar), you need to read carefully their specification. Be aware that stdio is often [buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer). Perhaps you'll need to use [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Then you could read a name into some data structure (I leave you to find out which ones), and you could read one character at a time using `getchar` to fill that data structure. Likewise you could output that data structure one character at a time using `putchar`.

Of course you'll use some [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) primitives (probably some kind of looping).

**We won't do your homework.**

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)....). Read documentation about your compiler (e.g. look into the [*Invoking GCC*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter). Of course, learn how to use the debugger (`gdb`, see [*Debugging with GDB*](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html))

You are the one starting to learn C programming. Be persevering, it takes some time (weeks or months of work). Read a few books, look into the source code of existing software in C (e.g. [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) on [github](http://github.com/)).

<sup>PS. For experts on C, doing your homework is trivial; however you should learn by yourself - the purpose of the homework is to teach you something - and if you copy a solution from elsewhere you won't learn anything</sup>